# OpenWrt bind non local IP

Tags: openwrt

I need to tell the operating system to allow applications to bind sockets to non-local IP addresses. I want to do that in OpenWrt linux terminal.

Using this command

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind
```

It shows

> ```
> net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 0
> ```

However when enabling it

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
```

it gives the error

> ```
> net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1 is an unknown key.
> ```

Can anyone solve this problem in OpenWrt?

Comment: Try `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1`, or try editing the line in `/etc/sysctl.conf` (I believe) and rebooting. Check that the setting was applied with `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind`.

Comment: @simlev Why didn't you post the `-w` solution as an answer? I didn't see your edited comment until I answered. If you write your own answer now, I will delete mine and give you credit.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski The reason I posted it as a comment is I don't have an OpenWRT system I could test it on. You go ahead this time ;-)

Comment: @simlev Let it be community wiki then. Feel free to add your advice about `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

[This manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl) says:

> To set a key, use the form `variable=value` [...] This requires the `-w` parameter to use.

(It looks like in my Debian `-w` is not required though; but in my OpenWRT it certainly is). Try:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
```

As an alternative, you can always edit the relevant line in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and reboot.

At any moment, you can check the current value with `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind`.